# How to solve this error for pollution rose?

Tags: r, error-messaging

I have an issue with R where I am trying to do a pollution rose graph and I am almost sure that the data and the code is correct but I still keep getting an error message and I couldn't figure out what does it mean. The error message is:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, vars[i], value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 37.
```

My code is:

```
pollutionRose(pollution_rose, pollutant = "PM10",header= TRUE, cols = c("darkblue","green4","yellow2","red","red4"), key.position = "bottom",max.freq = 50)
```

and here is my data:

```
HH:MM:SS    WD1 WS1 PM10 PM2.5  PM1
10:10:00 AM 0   0   0   0   0
10:20:00 AM 0   0   0   0   0
10:29:00 AM 254 0.4 0   0   0
10:30:00 AM 109 0.5 0   0   0
10:40:00 AM 21  1.9 0   0   0
10:50:00 AM 148 1.2 0   0   0
10:54:00 AM 222 1.1 0   0   0
10:55:00 AM 61  1   0   0   0
11:00:00 AM 109 0.6 19  4.3 1.8
11:10:00 AM 354 0.7 20.4    4.1 1.7
11:20:00 AM 5   2.6 8.3 3.8 1.6
11:29:00 AM 60  2.6 7.9 3.8 1.5
11:30:00 AM 97  1.5 18.6    3.8 1.5
11:40:00 AM 42  0.8 15.6    3.8 1.5
11:50:00 AM 52  0   10.5    4.3 1.6
12:00:00 PM 60  0.9 11.7    3.9 1.5
12:10:00 PM 74  1   9.6 4.1 1.4
12:20:00 PM 338 1.7 0   0   0
12:30:00 PM 285 4.4 0   0   0
12:40:00 PM 296 3.6 0   0   0
12:50:00 PM 241 3.3 0   0   0
1:00:00 PM  274 1.2 0   0   0
1:10:00 PM  287 1.3 15.8    4.4 1.6
1:20:00 PM  317 3   13.1    4.6 1.7
1:30:00 PM  309 2.6 10.5    3.5 1.4
1:31:00 PM  244 3.5 14.8    4.2 1.5
1:40:00 PM  251 0.9 12.8    4.1 1.5
1:50:00 PM  282 1.1 12.9    4.8 1.8
2:00:00 PM  254 2.5 9.6 4.9 1.7
2:10:00 PM  245 2.3 10.9    4.6 1.6
2:20:00 PM  207 2.1 0   0   0
2:30:00 PM  30  0   0   0   0
2:37:00 PM  62  0.7 12.9    4.3 1.6
2:40:00 PM  80  1.8 10.1    3.6 1.5
2:40:00 PM  0   0   10.1    3.6 1.5
2:50:00 PM  0   0   10  4.3 1.5
3:00:00 PM  0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: For people to help you, you need to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So, we also need data that we can run your code on to reproduce the problem ourselves.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In order to get good answers to your questions, you will need to follow certain conventions in asking.  It would be really helpful if you 1. Took the [tour of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and 2. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)